# Ignoring the data for specific tables while restoring mysql database from dump

Tags: mysql

I have a huge dump file with around 200 tables and millions of records for some of those tables.  I know it is possible to ignore specific tables when I do `mysqldump` .

Is it possible to ignore some tables or ignore just the insert queries for those tables while "restoring" the database from a dump?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to just restore the schema/structure of the table and ignore all the data?

Comment: I am restoring both schema and data but I want to igore the data for only one table out of 200 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with the mysql client.  The dump file is basically a big collection of CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (and some others), and the mysql client doesn't have any way of executing *part* of such an SQL script.

However, I have done it when necessary by being creative with `sed`.  For example, if I want to exclude the creation and data for table "do_not_want", I could do this:

```
cat mydumpfile.sql |
sed -e '/^-- Table structure for table .do_not_want./,/^UNLOCK TABLES;/d' |
mysql
```

This assumes that the patterns we're using for the boundaries don't occur in the data itself.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use the same to the insert statement in the dump?  Because the table I want to ignore has around 10 million records.  So the line for insert statement is a very large one.  Correct me if I am overthinking on this.

Comment: Yes, `sed` can process files with long lines.

Comment: @Slowcoder You should accept this answer! It works really well!