# How to exclude databases when importing to mysql

Tags: mysql

I am migrating from mysql to mariadb but I have problems when importing the whole backup I made before migration.

The backup include system tables, such as `mysql` so when importing, that database tries to be created, returning an error.

To restore, I am running this command: `mysql -u root -p < backupdb.sql` is there a way to exclude system databases?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: edit the file and remove them?  redo the backup and don't include them?

Comment: @ysth :-) :-) :-)

Comment: If you can't make a new backup excluding the schemas you don't want, then you're going to get some practice with `sed`. Use a solution similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080388/ignoring-the-data-for-specific-tables-while-restoring-mysql-database-from-dump/15080471#15080471